# cognito caching in Amplify V6

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to figure out if my application is designed as I expected. Currently in all my angular components in ngOnInit() I'm calling

```
    this.authenticatedUser = await this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.attributes = await this.authService.getUserAttributes();
```

I'm calling getUserAttributes because my app relies heavily on custom attributes in cognito user account. I'm concerned it might be excessive if Amplify isn't caching calls. I don't think it would cache the `fetchAuthSession (getRefreshedAuthenticatedUser())` call but what about the calls above? Are these coming back from a cache or everytime a user goes to a new component it's counting against me as cognito sync operations?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import {
  fetchAuthSession,
  getCurrentUser,
  signInWithRedirect,
  signOut,
  fetchUserAttributes,
  FetchUserAttributesOutput,
} from 'aws-amplify/auth';

export interface CustomUserAttributes extends FetchUserAttributesOutput {
  [key: string]: any;
}

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: environment.cognito.userPoolId,
      userPoolClientId: environment.cognito.appClientId,
      signUpVerificationMethod: 'code',
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: 'my-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
          scopes: [
            'email',
            'profile',
            'openid',
            'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
          ],
          redirectSignIn: [environment.redirectUrl],
          redirectSignOut: ['http://localhost:4200/'],
          responseType: 'code',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
const currentConfig = Amplify.getConfig();
console.log('currentConfig', currentConfig);

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  authIsLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  authDidFail = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authStatusChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
  public loggedIn = false;
  constructor() {
    this.signIn;
  }
  async getAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
      console.log('Attempting to get authenticated user');
      const user = await getCurrentUser();
      console.log(
        `User details - Username: ${user.username}, UserId: ${user.userId}`
      );
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error getting authenticated user', err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
  async getRefreshedAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
      const { accessToken, idToken } = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens ?? {};
      return { accessToken, idToken };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public async signIn(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await signInWithRedirect();
    } catch (err) {}
  }
  async logout() {
    try {
      await signOut();
      this.authStatusChanged.next(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async getUserAttributes(): Promise<CustomUserAttributes | null> {
    try {
      const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
      console.log('userAttributes', userAttributes);

      return userAttributes;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    }
  }

  async isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this.getAuthenticatedUser();

    return !!user && !!user.username;
  }
}
```

When I go to cloudwatch all I see are Signup Successes and TokenRefreshSuccesses. I don't see anything related to these calls.

```
    this.authenticatedUser = await this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.attributes = await this.authService.getUserAttributes();
```

What you see in screenshot is everything cognito related that's listed.

[image]

I appreciate any help on clearing up my concerns.